# AWS Glue AccessDeniedException Account <ID> is denied access

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, aws-glue

I am getting this message when I try to create a crawler on AWS Glue:

`{"service":"AWSGlue","statusCode":400,"errorCode":"AccessDeniedException","requestId":"RequestIDNumber","errorMessage":"Account <AccountID> is denied access.","type":"AwsServiceError"}`

already attached all those policies below to the IAM

[All my Policies here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VV9pM.png)

Already setup permissions to the AWS lake formation for the role too

Already created a custom policy kms to it too

And I am stucked, I cannot create a crawler!

I am in the root account, actually there`s no other account just the root, It's a super new account I created in AWS so I don't know what to do to be able to create this simple crawler

My ideia its to use it with dynamodb as data source

The message says there is something wrong with my account permission not with a role

Someone has an idea?

Thank you so much

Comment: The policies are for IAM role or your IAM user?

Comment: The role! I have just one user created and he has the following permissions: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1M-yntiS7UjrOcavLwoySTMLEbuvqrVCM/view?usp=sharing

Comment: my region is us-east-1

Comment: If your account is supper new, aws sometimes does not allow to access all its services immediately. Also using root account is a vary bad practice, which may explain why AWS cloud be limiting your account in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

I propose to  try using a separate user and attaching the policy you created to it.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure the reason, but loads of people have been having this issue. You can submit a ticket through AWS account support. I actually submitted two, including one through the unpaid support version and one through my paid account. They answered both tickets.

Basically, just tell them you need access to Glue and they should alter whatever it is to give you access. Sorry it's not a better answer, but I found no other useful information anywhere.